# node.js mySql server try to post with postman recive an err 1048

Tags: mysql, node.js

i built a server for sql an I'm trying to send a post by postman and recive an error 1048, when i'm doing the qurey with mysql on windows i'ts working just fine!

**index.js**

```
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  const q = "SELECT * FROM users";
  db.query(q, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    res.json(data);
  });
});

app.post("/users", (req, res) => {
  const q =
    "INSERT INTO `test`.`users` (`fname`, `lname`, `idnum`, `phone`, `email`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

  const values = [
    req.body.fname,
    req.body.lname,
    req.body.idnum,
    req.body.phone,
    req.body.email,
  ];
  db.query(q, values, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    data.message = "posted";
    res.json(data);
  });
});
```

and the error message on postman

```
{
    "code": "ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR",
    "errno": 1048,
    "sqlMessage": "Column 'fname' cannot be null",
    "sqlState": "23000",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "INSERT INTO `test`.`users` (`fname`, `lname`, `idnum`, `phone`, `email`) VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)"
}
```

[error message on postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAXmo.png)

and there is my table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EhFv.png)

i tried to query from the sql server, and from the node server and all works fine.
it's like the postman tranlate everythin to NULL.

Comment: The error seems clear: The value of `req.body.fname` (and all the other `req.body` properties) is `null` or `undefined`. What does `console.log(req.body)` show?

Answer (score 1):

I fixt it, in the postman body need to define to json insted text